# An unexpected increase of the number of rows after using dataframe.merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframes in a dictionary, and I want to merge all these dataframes using a common column "date". To do so, I used the following code :

```
n = len(dictionary)
something = dictionary[dictionnary_keys[0]]
for i in range(1,n):
     something = something.merge(dictionary[dictionnary_keys[i], on="date")
     print(something.shape)
```

Note that every dictionary's value is a pandas dataframe and its shape is (500,10).
When I run that code, I get a memory error because both number of rows and columns increase ... However, only the number of columns has to increase. I don't understand why I get this result.
Can someone explain me how to deal with such a situation ?
Thank you for your help. If you want more information, just let me know :)

Comment: Why do you use for-loop?

Comment: To use the merge function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have duplicated `date` values.

Here is a quick example:

```
# Generate dict of DatFrame with duplicated 'a'
d = dict()
for i in range(4):
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABBCD'), 'b':np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'c': i})

n = len(d)
s = d[0]
for i in range(1,n):
    s = s.merge(d[i], on="a")
    print(s.shape)
(7, 5)
(11, 7)
(19, 9)
```

Re-run with no duplicates:

```
d = dict()
for i in range(4):
    d[i] = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABCDE'), 'b':np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), 'c': i})
n = len(d)
s = d[0]
for i in range(1,n):
    s = s.merge(d[i], on="a")
    print(s.shape)
(5, 5)
(5, 7)
(5, 9)
```

Merging in this way might lead to complications with how your series are named:

```
   a  b_x  c_x  b_y  c_y  b_x  c_x  b_y  c_y
0  A    4    0    5    1    0    2    9    3
1  B    5    0    8    1    3    2    0    3
2  C    6    0    0    1    5    2    8    3
3  D    2    0    0    1    8    2    8    3
4  E    8    0    2    1    7    2    9    3

s['b_x']
   b_x  b_x
0    4    0
1    5    3
2    6    5
3    2    8
4    8    7
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What's the difference between your two codes ? About my dataframes, they definitely have no columns in common.

Comment: In the first example, Series `a` is `[A, B, B, C, D]`; whereas the second example it is `[A, B, C, D, E]`. To merge on a Series there must be shared values, if there are duplicate values in a DataFrame how do you determine which rows are merged with one another? pandas resolves this by giving you _all_ matches, this is why your DataFrames get bigger.

Comment: Indeed, you're right ! I noted that the 'data' series is different. However, I thought they were not... I'm gonna ask another question and hope you will answer to it as your explanations are great ! Thank you a lot Alex.